# NGINX GeoIP and detecting mobile at server level

Tags: redirect, mobile, nginx, geoip

What I am trying to do is setup NGINX to detect specific country codes. I have this working properly right now adding in lines such as 
`if ($geoip_country_code = IE) { rewrite ^(.*) http://link.com/for/Ireland;`
This is in my actual site config file not my nginx.conf file.

What I would like to also do is add in a mobile check to this, such as if it's Ireland AND mobile its will go to a second link. Is this even possible to do at this level? Or am I stuck just detecting the country at the server level then have to deal with mobile in a more standard way such as when the page is loading and using a mobile detection script. I know I can do it this way, but I would love to be able to add in the detection into the same catch in my NGINX config.

Thanks for all the help and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are far better off using code redirects than nginx configuration due to the incredible difference in user-agents for mobile. In particular, the cost of invoking a serie of `if` statements on nginx is non-trivial.

[This website](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) has a non-exhaustive list of mobile user-agents, old and not-so-old. You'll quickly see that the list is actually quite gianormous, to say the least. Let's focus on just iPhones, iPods and iPads for now. They're pretty easy to differentiate:

> Mozilla/5.0 (**device type**; **cpu type**; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3

So, this one will not pose problem. However, the string is very similar to other things, including Safari's desktop user-agent... And this is for the easiest of phones. Android has no such simplicity. Take, for instance, the HTC Desire:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; de-de; HTC Desire 1.19.161.5 Build/ERE27) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17

The identifier for the OS changed to the third field, which means that you now need a minimum of two regular expression engine calls to match iPhones and some android. I'm saying some, because... Well, let's go to the Motorola Droid:

> MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0

...Waaat?

Conclusion: you'll need a database of user-agents if you care about false positives. If you don't, just do broad checks on nginx using regular expressions on the user-agent, searching for the keywords iPad, iPhone, iPod, Android, Windows Phone. That will flag about 80-85% of all mobile users. If you want to match *everyone*, you'll need to use a DB of user-agents due to manufacturers re-writing their useragents.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for such a detailed response as to my issues doing it this way. I think I will be better off figuring out how to incorporate the checks for country where I pass the variable for setting my destination link in my actual website code vs in the config.

Comment: Country is fine in nginx - it's not that computationally expensive. It's the user-agent part you want to do in code due to the incredible complexity of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com. It has code snippet for nginx.
Recently I did such nginx configuration, works fine.